# Filtering Pandas DataFrame using a condition on column values that are numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, filtering

I have a Pandas DataFrame called 'dt', which has two columns called 'A' and 'B'.
The values of column 'B' are numpy arrays; Something like this:

```
index   A   B
0       a   [1,2,3]
1       b   [2,3,4]
2       c   [3,4,5]
```

Where:

```
type (dt["B"][0])
```

returns: numpy.ndarray

I want to filter this DataFrame to get another DataFrame, where only rows that have a certain element in the numpy array stored in 'B' are present.

I've tried this:

```
dt [element in dt["B"]]
```

So for example:

```
dt [2 in dt["B"]]
```

should return:

```
index   A   B
0       a   [1,2,3]
1       b   [2,3,4]
```

But this results in an error, namely "KeyError: True"

If the values of column "B" were strings, I could done the same with no error:

```
dt [dt["B"]==value]
```

So I wonder why my code doesn't work, and what does "KeyError: True" mean.

The complete error is this:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Applications/Conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-aa9ea046a48f> in <module>
----> 1 quotes_of_base["BTC" in quotes_of_base["quote"]]

~/Applications/Conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2798             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2799                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2800             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2801             if is_integer(indexer):
   2802                 indexer = [indexer]

~/Applications/Conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: True
```

Comment: Use `isin` not `in` as follows:`dt[dt["B"].isin(element)]`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- lets say you have something like:

  ```
        A         B
    0  10   [11, 0]
    1  20  [11, 10]
    2  30  [11, 10]
    3  40   [10, 0]
    4  50   [11, 0]
    5  60   [10, 0]
  ```

- And would like to filter only those in the array containing 10

  ```
        A         B
    1  20  [11, 10]
    2  30  [11, 10]
    3  40   [10, 0]
    5  60   [10, 0]
  ```

- You can use .apply

  ```
    #create the dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A','B'])
    df.A = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
    df.B = [[11,0],[11,10],[11,10],[10,0],[11,0],[10,0]]

    # results is a boolean indicating whether the value is found in the list
    # apply the filter in the column 'B' of the dataframe
    results = df.B.apply(lambda a: 10 in a)

    # filter the dataframe based on the boolean
    df_filtered = df[results]
    print(df_filtered)
  ```
- Then you get:

  ```
              A   B
    1         20  [11, 10]
    2         30  [11, 10]
    3         40   [10, 0]
    5         60   [10, 0]
  ```

> you can find more details at: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 2):

I used a combination of the commenters' answers. Note that when I read the data in the lists came in as strings so you might have to play with `str(2)` part of this.

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: True if str(2) in x['B'] else False, axis=1)]

   A        B
0  a  [1,2,3]
1  b  [2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that indexing the dataframe needs a list of True/False values, so if push comes to shove, you can still construct that list somewhere else (list comprehension/ for loop) and pass that into the df like `dt[contructed_true_false_list]`. Just make sure there is one entry per row of your df.

It's fairly difficult to suggest a solution without a concrete example but you might try something like this:

`[True if np.any(my_np_array == element) else False for my_np_array in dt["B"].values]`

Comment: I've added an example and the complete error. Would you please take another look? It seems to me that there should be an easier solution to this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: dt[[np.any(np.array(array)==2) for array in dt["B"]]] works just fine.

Comment: I have cast your ndarray into a simple array again, as the ndarray indicates multidimensional shenanigans. Not being able to see the original data, I added that in as a precaution, you might be able to omit that.